# Python Finding Index of Foreign Characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a simple script that prints index of given character in a string. However when the string includes letters which are not English , I got error.

```
def toBinary(character):  
binaryTable = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÇÜŞĞİ"
return binaryTable.index(character)+1
```

But when use the binaryTable array , in a function , for example I permutate it using my own method

```
def permutation(text_block,permutation_array,reverse):  
print permutation_array
temp = [None]*len(text_block)
temp_P = []
for i in permutation_array:
    temp_P.append(i)
i = 0
if reverse:
    #permutation_array.reverse()
    temp_P.reverse()
for integer in temp_P:
    temp [i] = text_block[integer]
    i += 1

return temp,temp_P
```

the array includes ascii characters like "\xc4" , "\xb0" .So when I run my binary converter method after permutation method it calls like

```
toBinary("\xc4")
```

Therefore I get "TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object" error in toBinary method.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: try using `try` and `except` commands?

Comment: Have you tried using encoding?  You might need the right encoding for the language you're expecting; for example:#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

u = u'abcdé'
print ord(u[-1])

Comment: thank you.How can I make it for Turkish alphabet?

Comment: I think it is latin5, so... `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÇÜŞĞİ".encode('latin5')`  gives you: `b'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\xc7\xdc\xde\xd0\xdd'`

Comment: ... and `b"\xc4".decode(encoding='latin5')` gives you: `'Ä'`